# Undo editing path in shell

Tags: powershell

I was trying to follow a online tutorial and wondered why they didn't have to use `".\"` in shell. Found this `$env:PATH =$env:PATH+";."` I tried it out but now I want to go back to the way it was. I've tried looking through the path manually, and I'm new to powershell. How would I remove something to my path in shell?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best way but you can do something like that. For example, to suppress the last path you added:

```
# Do an array with all paths
$currpath = $env:PATH.Split(";")

# Suppress the last path in the array
$newpath = $currpath[0..($currpath.Count -2)]

# Convert array into string and re-add it in the $env:PATH
$env:PATH = $newpath | % { $temp += $_ + ";" }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-replace` operator to replace it anywhere in the string:

```
$env:PATH = $env:PATH -replace '\.\\?;|;\.\\?$',''
```